# Selenium WebDriver - Unable to Click SubMenu which appears only on click and release of main menu

Tags: selenium

I am not able to click on the sub menu which is appearing on when mouse click and release.

**html tags:**

```
    <div class="ToolbarSubMenu" id="presentations" onmouseout="actionToolbarMenuSubMenuExit('presentations');" align="left" style="text-align: left; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1000; visibility: hidden;" parent="presentations_parent">
    <a id="hypothetical" class="ToolbarMenu" href="" onclick="onSelectMenuItem(201);;return false;">Hypothetical</a>
    <br><a id="profile" class="ToolbarMenu" href="" onclick="onSelectMenuItem(200);;return false;">Profile</a>
    <br><a id="rollingPeriods" class="ToolbarMenu" href="" onclick="onSelectMenuItem(542);;return false;">Rolling Periods</a>
    <br><a id="hiLo" class="ToolbarMenu" href="" onclick="onSelectMenuItem(540);;return false;">Hi / Lo</a>
    <br><a id="priceDistributions" class="ToolbarMenu" href="" onclick="onSelectMenuItem(541);;return false;">Price &amp; Distributions</a>
    <br><a id="exposureReport" class="ToolbarMenu" href="" onclick="onSelectMenuItem(204);;return false;">Exposure Report</a>
    <br>
</div>
<a id="presentations_parent" href="" class="ToolbarMenu" onclick="actionToolbarMenuClick('presentations');return false;">Presentations</a>
```

**Selenium Code :**

```
Actions act =new Actions(driver);

act.moveToElement(main).click().build().perform();   
act.release(main).build().perform();

 try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

WebElement hyp=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Hypothetical"));
hyp.click();
```

Comment: Sub menu comes on mouse hover or click?

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: Sub menu comes on mouse click ...

Comment: Exception is unable to click submenu web element

Answer (score 0):

I have issues sometimes with moving to elements i.e. drag drop features a bit like moveToElement.

I would suggest it is not clicking the element you are expecting.

Try to find the element by tag/id etc and clicking it for both the menu and sub menu items.

Also if animation occurs you need to allow a small delay or use the waituntil feature to get the sub menu element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried with id also no success. It clicks on main menu -> but submenu blinks and disappears immediately, tried with waituntil also and its not working..

Comment: Guys, can you help me out.. im stuck with this!!

Comment: Not sure if you are still using moveToElement.